# How can I toggle elements with dynamically created models using v-if?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to toggle visibility of input elements in a table (Buefy table). This toggling has to be done on the click of a checkbox.

The model data is generated dynamically after an API call and then assigned values (false by default)

I tried using ***this.nextTick(()=>{})*** too but it does not changes it.The event is being fired and the console.log too gives the values of the dynamically generated models

```
export default {
    name:'Dashboard',

        data() {
            return {
                maxMatches :{

                },
            }
        },

        mounted(){
            const ctx=this
            this.apiService.getLiveMatches().then(function(response){
                            for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                                ctx.data.push({'sr':i,'match_id':response[i]['match_id'],'match_title':response[i]['short_title'],'match_status':response[i]['status_note'],'start_date':response[i]['date_start'],'type':response[i]['domestic'],'priority':""})

                                // THis is where I am generating models dynamically

                                ctx.maxMatches[response[i]['match_id']]  = false
                            }
                            ctx.matchData = response
                        })

            this.apiService.getDomesticPriorities().then(function(response){
                    ctx.refreshDomesticUi(response)
            })
            this.apiService.getInternationalPriorities().then(function(response){
                    ctx.refreshInternationalUi(response)
            })




        },        

    }



// Template snippet goes here , this is a column of a table where the checkbox and input field resides


<b-table-column field="priority " label="Priority" >
   <div class="selection">
      <b-checkbox  @change.native="checkboxChanged(props.row)" :id="props.row.match_id"    :ref="props.row.type ==0 ? 'int'+props.row.sr+'-check-': 'dom'+props.row.sr+'-check' " ></b-checkbox>
      <b-field    
         :id="props.row.match_id +'b-field'" 
         v-if="maxMatches[props.row.match_id]"
         label="Quantity"
         type="is-danger"
         message="Quantity is invalid">
         <b-numberinput :id="props.row.match_id" ></b-numberinput>
      </b-field>
      <p > is this visible ???</p>
      <!-- <b-checkbox v-for="i in domChecks"   :key="i" :ref="props.row.type ==0 ? 'int'+props.row.sr+'-check-'+i : 'dom'+props.row.sr+'-check'+i " @click.native="checkBoxClick(props.row.type,props.row.sr,i)"></b-checkbox> -->
   </div>
</b-table-column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Vue.set(member, key, value).  The index operator will not be reactive.

```
Vue.set(ctx.maxMatches, response[i]['match_id'], false)
```

Comment: Sir, this worked . I never would have been able to find this on my own I guess. :P . Thank you so much . I wasted 3 days on it

Comment: We have all been there...  It is a shortcoming of Javascript, not Vue.  Golden rule number 1: Never use [ ] = on a reactive  object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `v-show` attribute on whatever element you want to toggle and data bind it to a variable which will toggle the element.